# Android java.lang.StackOverflowError TransitionDrawable

Tags: android, stack-overflow, transitiondrawable

I get a stackoverflow error when i apply a TransitionDrawable on textview:

```
private static void applyAnimationTransitionBackground(String descriptorValue, final Resources resources, View view){
Drawable currentBackground;
TransitionDrawable td;

if (view!=null){

    //Get current background or transparent color
    currentBackground = view.getBackground();
    if (currentBackground==null){
        currentBackground = new ColorDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);
    }

    //Create transition depend on trend
    if (descriptorValue.equals("1")){
        td= new TransitionDrawable (new Drawable []{currentBackground, new ColorDrawable(resources.getColor(R.color.positive_animation))}); 
    }else if (descriptorValue.equals("2")){
        td= new TransitionDrawable (new Drawable []{currentBackground, new ColorDrawable(resources.getColor(R.color.neutral_animation))});
    }else{
        td= new TransitionDrawable (new Drawable []{currentBackground, new ColorDrawable(resources.getColor(R.color.negative_animation))});
    }

    //Apply animation
    if (td!=null){
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(td);
        td.startTransition(500);
        //td.reverseTransition(500);            
    }else{
        Logger.error("applyAnimationTransitionBackground: TransitionDrawable is NULL");
    }   

}
```

}

```
02-12 17:00:12.899: I/System.out(11217): ---> M SAN nuevo valor 1,52%
02-12 17:00:12.907: I/System.out(11217): ---> M SAN nuevo valor SANTANDER
02-12 17:00:12.907: W/Resources(11217): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x11/d=0x55 a=-1}
02-12 17:00:12.907: W/Resources(11217): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0xfffffffe a=-1}
02-12 17:00:12.915: I/System.out(11217): ---> M SAN nuevo valor 1,52%
02-12 17:00:12.915: I/System.out(11217): ---> M SAN nuevo valor SANTANDER
02-12 17:00:12.915: W/Resources(11217): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x11/d=0x55 a=-1}
02-12 17:00:12.915: W/Resources(11217): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0xfffffffe a=-1}
02-12 17:00:12.915: I/dalvikvm(11217): threadid=1: stack overflow on call to Landroid/view/GLES20Canvas;.setupModifiers:IL
02-12 17:00:12.915: I/dalvikvm(11217):   method requires 40+20+20=80 bytes, fp is 0x4016b324 (36 left)
02-12 17:00:12.915: I/dalvikvm(11217):   expanding stack end (0x4016b300 to 0x4016b000)
02-12 17:00:12.915: I/dalvikvm(11217): Shrank stack (to 0x4016b300, curFrame is 0x4016e420)
02-12 17:00:12.915: D/AndroidRuntime(11217): Shutting down VM
02-12 17:00:12.915: W/dalvikvm(11217): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bd91f8)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217): java.lang.StackOverflowError
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawRect(GLES20Canvas.java:942)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawRect(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:226)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawRect(GLES20Canvas.java:952)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawRect(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:232)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable.draw(ColorDrawable.java:70)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
02-12 17:00:12.961: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):    at android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable.draw(TransitionDrawable.java:195)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure you call `applyAnimationTransitionBackground()` in a loop, for example `onDrawFrame()` of a `Renderer` (I say that just because I see usage of GL ES there but it may be an animation of some sort or another thing).

I thinks so because you set a background of `view`. At first background of `view` is a transition drawable between two colors - let's call it `T(C1, C2)`. For every successive call, the background of `view` is set to a transition drawable between:

1. current background of `view` and
2. some color drawable

In effect:

1. After second call, `view` background is set to a transition `T(T(C1, C2), C3)`.
2. After third call, `view` background is set to transition `T(T(T(C1, C2), C3), C4)`.
3. And so on...

In effect, even after 100 calls, you have a background drawable set to a *massive* combination of 100 transition drawables. You can imagine what is happening after 1000 or 10000 calls to your method. Since transition drawables simply delegate the drawing to their component drawables, you end up with a a stack overflow.

The simplest way to check if that is exactly the case would be to put the line `Logger.info("call");` in the beginning of `applyAnimationTransitionBackground()`. If you see lots of `call` messages in the logs (LogCat), then this is the case.

To fix the problem, you simply have to resign from this pattern of combining drawables. For example, you could save the last color values used for the transition and its start time. Then, when you need to create a transition between current color and a new one, you can use the saved start time and colors to interpolate the current color of the background. Then you can simply create a new transition drawable - between the current color and the new one.